# tab key behaviour in QWebView

Tags: qt, webkit, qwebview

I am using [Qt's implementation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/main-snapshot/qtwebkit.html) of [WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/) to create a rich text editor. This simple page:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body style="white-space:pre" contenteditable="true">
        test text
    </body>
</html>
```

when loaded in Firefox (17.0.1) or Chrome (23.0.1271.95) behaves as expected (pressing tab key would change focus but pasting a tab character inserts a tab, aligns the content following it to next tab stop - is not treated as a single space). Note that Chrome is based on WebKit.

Same page loaded inside QWebView has folowing body style:

```
 word-wrap: break-word;
 -webkit-nbsp-mode: space;
 -webkit-line-break:
 after-white-space;
 white-space: pre;
```

(according to build-in inspector).

When pressing the tab key following fragment gets inserted:

```
<span class="Apple-tab-span" style="white-space:pre"> </span>
```

and a simple space is rendered.

When pasting a tab character a single, simple space gets added (without the span tags above).

By saving the html with toHtml() method I can see that the characters are tab characters. So the problem is how to convince QWebView to render the tab "properly" (to align the content following it to next tab stop).

Qt version is 4.8.3 (actually build-ed from the trunk some month ago).